# Console application - go back up one line and add text to current line

Tags: console-application

I have been searching for this for some time, yet have had no luck discovering how to do it.

I would like to return to the previous line, and add text to it, a scenario with e.g. below

**E.g.**
When running `make` on some linux `makefile`'s, I noticed the following:

```
checking file ...... done
checking file2 ...... done
checking file3-long name ...... done
checking file4 ...... done
//etc
```

This would be done with a similar & basic psuedocode concept (to my knowledge and understanding).

```
std::cout << "checking: " << fileName << " ........ " << std::endl;
runCheck(fileName)
std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
```

This will output:

> checking: {fileName} ........
>
> done

Is there a way I can add the done after the ellipse?

I recall reading something on ncurses, and a few other libs, but I would prefer if this can be done purely using Qt

Thanks in advance

Comment: if someone down votes this question,  please leave a comment as to why you have done so, thus I will be able to learn from my mistake(s) and ask beter questions in  the future, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to do at a classical console application. The console is just a stream, you can't go back and change stuff, what is done is done. If you want to signify update, then output the same line with the update.

Alternatively, if all you want to do is have the `done` at the same line, just skip the last `std::endl`. Then there will be no need to go back at all.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't accomplished by backing up a line. Instead, the initial part of the line is output without the newline, and then when the "done" portion is printed, it continues on the current line. This isn't actually a Qt question; your sample code is pure C++ without any Qt, but all that you need to do is remove the "std::endl" from the line that prints "checking:".